# Strange colors in Ubuntu (green tint, 14.04 LTS)

Tags: ati, graphics, dell, colors

I have a Dell Inspiron 17R 5737 with an Intel Haswell Core i5 4200U, and an AMD Radeon HD8870 graphics card (switchable).

When installing Ubuntu (after checking disk for errors) and choosing "Try without installing", there's a green tint on the whole screen (where it's supposed to be pink/purple). I thought it might just be an issue that wouldn't show up after installing it onto the hard drive, and so I went on with the installation without any problems.
My computer rebooted and I booted Ubuntu for some tweaking.

But the green tint was still there. I tried plugging in my LG HDTV via HDMI and on that screen there was no tint, but it was still there on my laptop.

What I'm wondering is why this happens and if there's any way to fix it, because I would really like to be able to use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I know this old now, but I was experiencing this too. It happened to me after loosing grub2. I had to install it from a live CD.

The desktop remained with a dodgy green hue to it until I updated grub. Try this and see if it works:

```
sudo update-grub
```

after rebooting the green hue was fixed. maybe just be correlation rather causation, but worth a shot if you are still having problems.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same thing on my own Inspiron 17R: [Color Problems on New Install of 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577803/color-problems-on-new-install-of-14-04)

A band-aid is to boot with kernel-mode-setting disabled. Add `nomodeset` after 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT= "nomodeset"` in `/etc/default/grub`).

I'm pretty sure this disables hardware accelerated graphics, but if you're not doing graphics intensive work it at least fixes the colors.