# Color Problems on New Install of 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video, screen, monitor, color-depth

I'm new to Ubuntu (and Linux), and just installed it next to Windows 7 on my Dell Inspiron 5737.

Everything seems to have worked great except that the color is very messed up on my screen. It is only displaying purple and green, and dithering the color to get value differences. This doesn't appear on the grub screen, but shows up immediately after.

The weird thing is that the color is fine under Windows 7 on both my internal laptop screen and my TV over HDMI *and fine as well under Ubuntu on the TV!*.
I've checked other live trials of other distributions as well, and have the same problem.

The video card is a:

```
product:       Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller 
vendor:        Intel Corporation physical id: 2 bus 
info:          pci@0000:00:02.0 
version:       09 
width:         64 bits 
clock:         33MHz 
capabilities:  msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 
resources:     irq:60 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

Also, I already tried the Intel driver installer, which didn't change anything.

**[Here are pictures](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5JVeramRd-zU1lQeGt6YXJCajQ&usp=sharing)** of the way the screen looks, and **[here are screenshots](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5JVeramRd-zckpmZXpqcmZNVmc&usp=sharing)** (problem doesn't show up in screenshots)

Exporting `.icm` files from Windows to Ubuntu `.icc` files and trying to recalibrate the screen didn't work.

Adding kernel boot parameter `vga=868` (closest to my native resolution) doesn't help either...

Edit:
I've found a half solution to the problem. If I boot with kernel-mode-setting disabled (add "nomodeset" after "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" in /etc/default/grub) the color works fine. However, the intel video driver doesn't work with non-kernel mode setting, and it reverts to the vesa driver. This makes things slow and disables a lot of features. I'd still like to get the Intel driver working properly.

Comment: Bug fixed in later release as discussed [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204287&page=3)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a half solution to the problem. If I boot with kernel-mode-setting disabled (add "nomodeset" after "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" in /etc/default/grub) the color works fine. However, the intel video driver doesn't work with non-kernel mode setting, and it reverts to the vesa driver. This makes things slow and disables a lot of features. I'd still like to get the Intel driver working properly.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer? If yes, accept it. If no, then perhaps you want to add it to the question as _update_ to the situation?