# Green Tint on Screen During Normal Boot

Tags: resolution

I have a dell inspiron 17r which has an Intel hd graphics 4400 video card and I get this strange green tint whenever I do a normal boot of Ubuntu 14.04. However, if I connect to hdmi on my tv, the screen color is normal for the tv. Also, if I boot in recovery mode the screen color is normal. Can anybody tell me what's going on? I've update my grub and I still have the same issue. Or is there a way I can edit a script that allows me to start in failsafe graphics mode every time (I'm assuming this is how recovery mode starts)?

HELP!!!!! I CAN NOT USE WINDOWS ANYMORE. I AM AT MY WITS

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with the same hardware: [Color Problems on New Install of 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577803/color-problems-on-new-install-of-14-04)

A band-aid is to boot with kernel-mode-setting disabled (add `nomodeset` after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` in `/etc/default/grub`). I'm pretty sure this disables hardware accelerated graphics, but if you're not doing graphics intensive work it at least fixes the colors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've tried this already and it fixes the color issue. However, this boots some drivers into a recovery like state. The HDMI output for example is disabled because it's initialized through the linux graphics module which is disabled by  the nomodeset option... That being said, have you experienced this? If so, any more work arounds? :p

Comment: @Cody, this is at best a temporary solution.  Please see http://askubuntu.com/a/772032/233794