# How to change Graphics Driver in 16.04 from i915 to open source driver?

Tags: graphics, suspend, 16.04

Noob Question, so please don't get annoyed!

I upgraded from 15.04 to 16.04 LTS, and now my system reboots often for no reason, doesn't "suspend" etc..

I have a Lenovo with Intel Core i5, and AMD Radeon Graphics. I checked the forums for solutions, but I haven't got a solution. I checked (`lshw -c video`) and got the following:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

How do I "use the open source graphics driver" as suggested by Ubuntu Forums?

I am on the verge of downgrading to 15.04 until a proper solution is found and annouced. It's going to be a pain, so I thought I'd ask here before proceeding.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions...
Rajan

Comment: Output of `glxinfo | grep render` or  `fglrxinfo | grep render`

Comment: You have what I have - a dual graphics system with onboard power-saving GPU that you output in lshw -c, and a discreet ATI GPU, using AMDGPU open source driver, but it's not activated, i.e. it's not being used by the system as primary graphics. Give us a VGA controller of lspci.

Comment: ~$ lspci: 
    `00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a2e (rev 09)`

Comment: I did the update of the kernel but could not solve. The system crashed. I will reinstall 14.04 until a final solution as I can't working having pc crashing random with ubuntu 16 and 945 card using i915 driver

Answer (score 12):

I was finally able to fix the i915 problem by updating from kernel 4.4.0-22 to 4.5.1. On my 64 bit machine with ubuntu 16.04 xenial I ran:

```
    % wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.1-wily/linux-headers-4.5.1-040501_4.5.1-040501.201604121331_all.deb

    % wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.1-wily/linux-headers-4.5.1-040501-generic_4.5.1-040501.201604121331_amd64.deb

    % wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.1-wily/linux-image-4.5.1-040501-generic_4.5.1-040501.201604121331_amd64.deb

    % sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

DEAR UBUNTU DEVELOPERS, the DRM issue with i915 appears to be fixed as from kernel version 4.5.1. I tried version 4.4.10 and it did not fix the DRM issue. I would appreciate if the changes to DRM in connection with i915 were backported into the official xenial kernel.

Comment: Same issue here with 4.4.0-21 (and 4.4.0-28) kernel on 64-bit Bay Trail-based machine with Lubuntu. Lot of suggests to fix it, but update kernel works for me.

Comment: Since yesterday I am [no longer able to log on to any DE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/806242/16-04-there-is-only-the-wallpaper-after-logging-in) in a laptop with a Sky Lake card and I suspect it is also a drivers issue. However, installing this newer kernel did not fix it in my case.

Comment: This is totally the best answer.  Out there, most answers recommend the "nomodeset" option in `/etc/default/grub`, but this IS NOT the long term solution; it will bring an even powerful computer to it's knees, carrying the graphics onboard.  Using the kernel update solution, checking "About this computer" your graphics card will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled my 16.04 system while installing a SSD and ran into this same problem. I ran for a couple of hours using nomodeset and then i915.modeset=0, both as grub parameters until I read your question.

My 16.04 install had make kernel 4.15.0-29 the default and even after downloading the correct firmware files, I only could boot with the modeset trick.

I solved it the same as the previous answer to this question. Installing kernel 4.5.1. In my case, a kernel downgrade.