# Ubuntu 16.04 graphics crashes with Intel graphics

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics

I just updated a laptop to Ubuntu 16.04, and now I see the following problem. At random moments (but when some graphics activity is going on, such as opening a window), the display garbles and the computer freezes. The only thing one can do is to power it off forcefully; which of course loses any kernel log entries there may have been.

What can I do about this? dmesg (after a boot) lists a few ominous looking stack traces related to graphics:

```
[    2.220658] [drm] initialized overlay support
[    2.220751] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20151010 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    2.240350] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    2.240439] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 82 at /build/linux-Ay7j_C/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:1215
5 intel_atomic_check+0x2fd/0x6b0 [i915]()
[    2.240443] WARN_ON(!connector_state->crtc)
[    2.240446] Modules linked in:
[    2.240449]  ahci psmouse i915 firewire_ohci libahci b44 i2c_algo_bit pata_acpi drm_kms_helper ssb syscopyarea m
ii sysfillrect firewire_core sysimgblt fb_sys_fops crc_itu_t drm wmi fjes video
[    2.240477] CPU: 0 PID: 82 Comm: kworker/u4:3 Not tainted 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu
[    2.240481] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq nx7300 (RU460EA#ABH)/30A2, BIOS 68YGU Ver. F.0C 07/25/2007
[    2.240489] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
[    2.240492]  0000000000000286 000000003c6593a8 ffff880035ae39a0 ffffffff813e93c3
[    2.240498]  ffff880035ae39e8 ffffffffc0215a50 ffff880035ae39d8 ffffffff81080f62
[    2.240503]  ffff880034e08800 ffff880034e0a800 ffff880034e08800 0000000000000000
[    2.240508] Call Trace:
[    2.240516]  [<ffffffff813e93c3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[    2.240522]  [<ffffffff81080f62>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    2.240526]  [<ffffffff81080ffc>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[    2.240569]  [<ffffffffc0045f9d>] ? drm_atomic_add_affected_planes+0x7d/0xd0 [drm]
[    2.240628]  [<ffffffffc01b356d>] intel_atomic_check+0x2fd/0x6b0 [i915]
[    2.240657]  [<ffffffffc004680e>] drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
[    2.240686]  [<ffffffffc0046cfd>] ? drm_atomic_set_fb_for_plane+0x2d/0x90 [drm]
[    2.240715]  [<ffffffffc0046c27>] drm_atomic_commit+0x17/0x60 [drm]
[    2.240773]  [<ffffffffc01b71e5>] intel_get_load_detect_pipe+0x3d5/0x530 [i915]
[    2.240833]  [<ffffffffc01f08ed>] intel_tv_detect+0x13d/0x5f0 [i915]
[    2.240861]  [<ffffffffc00412de>] ? drm_get_edid+0x3e/0x3f0 [drm]
[    2.240884]  [<ffffffffc00d9da5>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x235/0x4d0 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.240896]  [<ffffffffc00da053>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes+0x13/0x20 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.240910]  [<ffffffffc00e691e>] drm_fb_helper_initial_config+0xae/0x420 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.240967]  [<ffffffffc01c74bb>] intel_fbdev_initial_config+0x1b/0x20 [i915]
[    2.240972]  [<ffffffff810a2f28>] async_run_entry_fn+0x48/0x150
[    2.240977]  [<ffffffff81099ff2>] process_one_work+0x162/0x480
[    2.240981]  [<ffffffff8109a35b>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
[    2.240986]  [<ffffffff8109a310>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
[    2.240990]  [<ffffffff810a0528>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[    2.240994]  [<ffffffff810a0450>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[    2.241000]  [<ffffffff8182488f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
[    2.241004]  [<ffffffff810a0450>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[    2.241008] ---[ end trace 9c3f9641e06cab07 ]---
[    2.241013] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    2.241072] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 82 at /build/linux-Ay7j_C/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:11693 intel_plane_atomic_calc_changes+0x567/0x6c0 [i915]()
[    2.241075] WARN_ON(was_visible)
[    2.241077] Modules linked in:
[    2.241079]  ahci psmouse i915 firewire_ohci libahci b44 i2c_algo_bit pata_acpi drm_kms_helper ssb syscopyarea mii sysfillrect firewire_core sysimgblt fb_sys_fops crc_itu_t drm wmi fjes video
[    2.241103] CPU: 0 PID: 82 Comm: kworker/u4:3 Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu
[    2.241106] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq nx7300 (RU460EA#ABH)/30A2, BIOS 68YGU Ver. F.0C 07/25/2007
[    2.241111] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
[    2.241114]  0000000000000286 000000003c6593a8 ffff880035ae3888 ffffffff813e93c3
[    2.241119]  ffff880035ae38d0 ffffffffc0215a50 ffff880035ae38c0 ffffffff81080f62
[    2.241124]  0000000000000001 ffff8800356ed000 ffff880034da9540 ffff88003545f800
[    2.241129] Call Trace:
[    2.241133]  [<ffffffff813e93c3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[    2.241137]  [<ffffffff81080f62>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    2.241141]  [<ffffffff81080ffc>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[    2.241199]  [<ffffffffc01b8e87>] intel_plane_atomic_calc_changes+0x567/0x6c0 [i915]
[    2.241211]  [<ffffffffc00da33b>] ? drm_plane_helper_check_update+0xdb/0x190 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.241268]  [<ffffffffc01991d0>] intel_plane_atomic_check+0x140/0x1f0 [i915]
[    2.241281]  [<ffffffffc00e1a68>] drm_atomic_helper_check_planes+0x48/0x1c0 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.241339]  [<ffffffffc01b3400>] intel_atomic_check+0x190/0x6b0 [i915]
[    2.241367]  [<ffffffffc004680e>] drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
[    2.241396]  [<ffffffffc0046cfd>] ? drm_atomic_set_fb_for_plane+0x2d/0x90 [drm]
[    2.241425]  [<ffffffffc0046c27>] drm_atomic_commit+0x17/0x60 [drm]
[    2.241482]  [<ffffffffc01b71e5>] intel_get_load_detect_pipe+0x3d5/0x530 [i915]
[    2.241542]  [<ffffffffc01f08ed>] intel_tv_detect+0x13d/0x5f0 [i915]
[    2.241571]  [<ffffffffc00412de>] ? drm_get_edid+0x3e/0x3f0 [drm]
[    2.241583]  [<ffffffffc00d9da5>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x235/0x4d0 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.241595]  [<ffffffffc00da053>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes+0x13/0x20 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.241608]  [<ffffffffc00e691e>] drm_fb_helper_initial_config+0xae/0x420 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.241666]  [<ffffffffc01c74bb>] intel_fbdev_initial_config+0x1b/0x20 [i915]
[    2.241671]  [<ffffffff810a2f28>] async_run_entry_fn+0x48/0x150
[    2.241675]  [<ffffffff81099ff2>] process_one_work+0x162/0x480
[    2.241679]  [<ffffffff8109a35b>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
[    2.241683]  [<ffffffff8109a310>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
[    2.241687]  [<ffffffff810a0528>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[    2.241691]  [<ffffffff810a0450>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[    2.241695]  [<ffffffff8182488f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
[    2.241699]  [<ffffffff810a0450>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[    2.241702] ---[ end trace 9c3f9641e06cab08 ]---
[    2.352069] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    2.352171] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 82 at /build/linux-Ay7j_C/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:12732 intel_modeset_check_state+0x563/0x8a0 [i915]()
[    2.352176] encoder's enabled state mismatch (expected 0, found 1)
[    2.352179] Modules linked in: ahci psmouse i915 firewire_ohci libahci b44 i2c_algo_bit pata_acpi drm_kms_helper ssb syscopyarea mii sysfillrect firewire_core sysimgblt fb_sys_fops crc_itu_t drm wmi fjes video
[    2.352221] CPU: 0 PID: 82 Comm: kworker/u4:3 Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu
[    2.352225] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq nx7300 (RU460EA#ABH)/30A2, BIOS 68YGU Ver. F.0C 07/25/2007
[    2.352235] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
[    2.352240]  0000000000000286 000000003c6593a8 ffff880035ae3960 ffffffff813e93c3
[    2.352248]  ffff880035ae39a8 ffffffffc0215a50 ffff880035ae3998 ffffffff81080f62
[    2.352254]  ffff880034e08b18 ffff880035589600 ffff880034e08b48 ffff880034e08b30
[    2.352261] Call Trace:
[    2.352272]  [<ffffffff813e93c3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[    2.352279]  [<ffffffff81080f62>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    2.352285]  [<ffffffff81080ffc>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[    2.352347]  [<ffffffffc01ef9f7>] ? intel_tv_get_hw_state+0x27/0x50 [i915]
[    2.352394]  [<ffffffffc01a6433>] intel_modeset_check_state+0x563/0x8a0 [i915]
[    2.352440]  [<ffffffffc01b1bcb>] intel_atomic_commit+0x4bb/0x6f0 [i915]
[    2.352472]  [<ffffffffc0046c47>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
[    2.352518]  [<ffffffffc01b71e5>] intel_get_load_detect_pipe+0x3d5/0x530 [i915]
[    2.352566]  [<ffffffffc01f08ed>] intel_tv_detect+0x13d/0x5f0 [i915]
[    2.352589]  [<ffffffffc00412de>] ? drm_get_edid+0x3e/0x3f0 [drm]
[    2.352606]  [<ffffffffc00d9da5>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x235/0x4d0 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.352615]  [<ffffffffc00da053>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes+0x13/0x20 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.352626]  [<ffffffffc00e691e>] drm_fb_helper_initial_config+0xae/0x420 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.352672]  [<ffffffffc01c74bb>] intel_fbdev_initial_config+0x1b/0x20 [i915]
[    2.352676]  [<ffffffff810a2f28>] async_run_entry_fn+0x48/0x150
[    2.352680]  [<ffffffff81099ff2>] process_one_work+0x162/0x480
[    2.352683]  [<ffffffff8109a35b>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
[    2.352687]  [<ffffffff8109a310>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
[    2.352690]  [<ffffffff810a0528>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[    2.352693]  [<ffffffff810a0450>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[    2.352698]  [<ffffffff8182488f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
[    2.352701]  [<ffffffff810a0450>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[    2.352704] ---[ end trace 9c3f9641e06cab09 ]---
[    2.380278] firewire_core 0000:02:06.1: created device fw0: GUID 00023f9929c9140e, S400
[    2.424067] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    2.424151] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 82 at /build/linux-Ay7j_C/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_display.c:12155 intel_atomic_check+0x2fd/0x6b0 [i915]()
[    2.424156] WARN_ON(!connector_state->crtc)
[    2.424159] Modules linked in:
[    2.424163]  ahci psmouse i915 firewire_ohci libahci b44 i2c_algo_bit pata_acpi drm_kms_helper ssb syscopyarea mii sysfillrect firewire_core sysimgblt fb_sys_fops crc_itu_t drm wmi fjes video
[    2.424196] CPU: 0 PID: 82 Comm: kworker/u4:3 Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu
[    2.424201] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq nx7300 (RU460EA#ABH)/30A2, BIOS 68YGU Ver. F.0C 07/25/2007
[    2.424208] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
[    2.424213]  0000000000000286 000000003c6593a8 ffff880035ae39e8 ffffffff813e93c3
[    2.424220]  ffff880035ae3a30 ffffffffc0215a50 ffff880035ae3a20 ffffffff81080f62
[    2.424227]  ffff880034e08800 ffff880034e0a800 ffff880034e08800 0000000000000000
[    2.424234] Call Trace:
[    2.424241]  [<ffffffff813e93c3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[    2.424248]  [<ffffffff81080f62>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[    2.424253]  [<ffffffff81080ffc>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[    2.424261]  [<ffffffff811eebf4>] ? __kmalloc_track_caller+0x1b4/0x250
[    2.424330]  [<ffffffffc01b356d>] intel_atomic_check+0x2fd/0x6b0 [i915]
[    2.424356]  [<ffffffffc004680e>] drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
[    2.424380]  [<ffffffffc0046cf0>] ? drm_atomic_set_fb_for_plane+0x20/0x90 [drm]
[    2.424402]  [<ffffffffc0046c27>] drm_atomic_commit+0x17/0x60 [drm]
[    2.424449]  [<ffffffffc01b7460>] intel_release_load_detect_pipe+0x120/0x160 [i915]
[    2.424497]  [<ffffffffc01f0aeb>] intel_tv_detect+0x33b/0x5f0 [i915]
[    2.424508]  [<ffffffffc00d9da5>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes_merge_bits+0x235/0x4d0 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.424517]  [<ffffffffc00da053>] drm_helper_probe_single_connector_modes+0x13/0x20 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.424528]  [<ffffffffc00e691e>] drm_fb_helper_initial_config+0xae/0x420 [drm_kms_helper]
[    2.424575]  [<ffffffffc01c74bb>] intel_fbdev_initial_config+0x1b/0x20 [i915]
[    2.424578]  [<ffffffff810a2f28>] async_run_entry_fn+0x48/0x150
[    2.424582]  [<ffffffff81099ff2>] process_one_work+0x162/0x480
[    2.424585]  [<ffffffff8109a35b>] worker_thread+0x4b/0x4c0
[    2.424588]  [<ffffffff8109a310>] ? process_one_work+0x480/0x480
[    2.424591]  [<ffffffff810a0528>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[    2.424595]  [<ffffffff810a0450>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[    2.424599]  [<ffffffff8182488f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
[    2.424602]  [<ffffffff810a0450>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
[    2.424605] ---[ end trace 9c3f9641e06cab0a ]---
```

and some more (but they seem quite similar).

Typing `lshw -c video` I get this:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display:0        
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f4400000-f447ffff ioport:4000(size=8) memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f4480000-f44bffff
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f4500000-f457ffff
```

Reinstalling the X drivers, as in [16.04 - How To Purge Intel Default Drivers & Reinstall Intel Graphic Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763672/16-04-how-to-purge-intel-default-drivers-reinstall-intel-graphic-drivers) didn't help.
Under previous Ubuntu versions, this problem did not exist although some 3D operations (such as the rotating desktop cube) didn't quite do the perspective transformations right.

Comment: A temporary fix is available, see http://askubuntu.com/a/772032 Hope this helps!

Comment: @dzmanto: I tried the 4.5.1 kernel as in your answer to that question, but alas, it does not help for my case. If I repeat zoom-to-fullscreen and zoom-back a few times, the problem shows itself. (The screen gets horizontal black bars in between coloured stripes of the purple background colour.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug when the system freezes or when it crashes back to login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38367/how-do-i-debug-when-the-system-freezes-or-when-it-crashes-back-to-login)

Comment: @David Foerster: I looked at that question; its answers seem to revolve around recovering X logs. However in my case the computer is completely frozen, so that it doesn't get a chance to log anything. .xsession-errors..old nor Xorg.0.log.old contain anything interesting, unfortunately.

Comment: This does not seem to be X-Realted. I saw it on my Intel D945GSEJT-Based Server without X and only(!) when no Display was connected. Updating to 4.5.7 solved the issue.

Comment: It would help a lot if you list here your repositories (at least drivers-related repos) in search of a conflictive one. That's how I solve this crashing/freezing issue on my Intel Laptop. Right now I have: `OS: Ubuntu 16.10, Kernel: 4.7.2-040702-generic (x86_64), Desktop: Unity 7.5.0, Display Server: X Server 1.18.4, Display Driver: modesetting 1.18.4, OpenGL: 3.3 Mesa 12.0.3, Vulkan: 1.0.21, Compiler: GCC 6.2.0 20161005, File-System: ext4, Screen Resolution: 1366x768` and doing just fine after purging conflictive repos.

Comment: Note for reference: I don't work at this organisaton any more and don't have access to this laptop any more.

Comment: I noticed crashing with `intel i915` drivers when running any GPU bound process on older intel processors.
The best solution that would stop the crashing was to switch the `driver` option in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to `fbdev`.
This limits GPU acceleration, but not as badly as `nomodesetting` in the kernel options. Try this switch for any crashing driver.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. open software & updates
2. Go to additional Driver
3. select intel graphics
4. Restart your pc/laptop

Comment: tell me the list of options

Comment: @FakabbirAmin Get out of this question thread then, as the question is about issues with Intel Graphics. Ask your own question, please.