# Cannot boot 16.04 in normal and recovery mode. Only can with upstart mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, upstart

I upgraded to 16.04, and now when booting with the default kernel the system freezes at the purple screen with dots after some seconds. I tried recovery mode and it also freezes after doing some work. It only boots when I try the upstart option in the advanced options.

My system is a Dell Inspiron mini 10

The last  printed lines are (in recovery mode)

```
[ OK ] Started Braille Device Support.
       Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data ....
       Starting Recovery Mode Menu....
[ OK ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
```

Then it freezes.

Comment: It seems hardware or kernel lock. I've been through it, in my case, it was due to video driver... While it's trying to boot, press Ctrl-Alt-F2 to see startup log, watch when it freezes and tell the result or post a photo of into your question

Comment: The last printed lines are(in recovery mode) ..... [OK] Started Braille Device Support. Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data .... Starting Recovery Mode Menu.... [OK] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.

Then it freezes.

Comment: Is NVIDIA your video driver? See that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/778193/system-hangs-on-starting-show-plymouth-boot-screen

Comment: *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:fd000000-fd3fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8

Comment: that is the output of the command :lshw -c video and the information of driver i915 is:modinfo i915
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-93-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation

Comment: Look this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/767429/ubuntu-16-04-graphics-crashes-with-intel-graphics

Comment: Another commentary:  I can boot ubuntu 16.04 from an usb live normally in the TRY option. The version with booting problems is the upgrade version

Comment: SOLVED:  I have solved the problem!!.   It is a bug: Bug 1253523       SOLVED BY Iván Jiménez  2015-11-02 23:28:31 EST 
This bug is caused by the file /var/lib/systemd/backlight/platform-dell-laptop:leds:dell::kbd_backlight created by (I guess) systemd-backlight@.service, because I can boot with kernel-4.2.3-200.fc22.x86_64 after I remove that file.

As that file is re-created at shutdown, I have to mask the service systemd-backlight@leds\:dell\:\:kbd_backlight.service with:

sudo systemctl mask systemd-backlight@leds\:dell\:\:kbd_backlight.service 

.  THANKS VERY MUCH

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED: I have solved the problem!!. It is a bug: Bug 1253523 SOLVED BY Iván Jiménez 2015-11-02 23:28:31 EST . He wrote: This bug is caused by the file /var/lib/systemd/backlight/platform-dell-laptop:leds:dell::k‌​bd_backlight created by (I guess) systemd-backlight@.service, because I can boot with kernel-4.2.3-200.fc22.x86_64 after I remove that file. As that file is re-created at shutdown, I have to mask the service systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service with: sudo systemctl mask systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service .     I followed his intructions and  now  it boots normally. THANKS VERY MUCH

Comment: EDIT: He suggest adding the following kernel parameter: systemd.restore_state=0 instead of sudo systemctl mask systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service. Note , I have a 32 bits kernel. So the bug not only affects 64 bits.