# Acer H243H external monitor distorted in Ubuntu 16.04 and up

Tags: acer, monitor, display-resolution

I've been using an Acer H243H monitor for a while with Linux for a while without problems, but now, I've been having serious distortion problems.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and any Linux distro based upon that version, the screen distorts, colors changing, and the resolution goes down. Horizontal lines move from the top to the bottom of the screen.

[image]

In the picture, I am using Linux Mint, but it still happens with normal Ubuntu 16.04.Is there any way I can fix this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering about this too. Ubuntu based distrubutions always do this to me. Manjaro is the only one that I haven't had this happen before. The only fix I know is is using

`xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 60`

Do you by any chance use 144hz monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue with a fresh 16.04 that I reinstalled because having this issue with a previous 14.04 LTS and after years working well, one day ... started to output like the picture. After google around, have managed to recover it. Hope it helps to anybody.

First we create a new monitor mode (this data is extracted from cvt 1920 1080 60, just copy what it goes after the modeline name):

```
xrandr --newmode 1920x1080T 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -HSync +VSync
```

Now this new screen mode created (1920x1080T) we are going to add it to the monitor capabilities, in my case the HDMI1 output (you can see the possible outputs names by typing xrandr command alone):

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080T
```

if you type again xrandr, it will appear in the list of the HDMI1.

Now you must use this new mode to correct the problem:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080T
```

That's all! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an Acer P235H monitor and Ubuntu 16.04 using the 4.4 kernel.

I have a Lenovo with built-in Intel graphics using the i915 driver.

I noticed issues relating to the i915 driver in the dmesg output and eventually found a slightly related issue ([How to change Graphics Driver in 16.04 from i915 to open source driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766931/how-to-change-graphics-driver-in-16-04-from-i915-to-open-source-driver)) that mentioned an issue in kernel 4.4 being fixed in 4.5 and above the related to he i915 driver.

By opting in to the rolling kernel upgrade program I updated from kernel version 4.4 to 4.10 which solved this issue.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

More info regarding the rolling kernel updates:

- [Old kernel with Ubuntu 16.04.2 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882896/old-kernel-with-ubuntu-16-04-2-update)
- [What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)