# Ubunu stuck at login screen screen since using NVIDIA graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, graphics, login

I upgraded my system with a Geforce 1060 three weeks ago and after I installed the necessary [NVIDIA driver](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/download/driverResults.aspx/105373/en-uk) everything was running fine.
But after couple of days Ubuntu(16.04 LTS 64bit) booted with the lowest possible resolution and stucked in a login loop.

I switched to the command line and went through the logs but strangely, could not find anything suspicious. I googled and went through all the suggestion you find when you google for ["Ubuntu stuck in login loop"](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ubuntu%20stuck%20in%20login%20loop), but nothing solved my problem.

Eventually I reinstalled the NVIDIA driver and got the GUI running again.
But now, every 4 to 6 days, I have got to go through the same process, Ubuntu stucks in login and I have to install the NVIDIA driver again.

Does anybody have similar problems?

Comment: Generally you do not want to install the .run files directly from nVidia. You have to update with dpkg commands each time you get new kernel or other major updates. And if you reinstall from repository, you must be sure to purge  current install or you get major conflicts. http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers Or command line (same as the 14.04 options shown). But since new 1060, you will need to add ppa first, to be able to get even newer drivers preconfigure for Ubuntu. https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.

Comment: I had similar problems. After 5 hours of trying everything through Ubuntu and Grub, I just ended up reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a fairly common issue and a common duplicate question. U can find many answers here, but one question u should ask urself is if you have UEFI or EFI based BIOS. If so, u may have a proprietary issue which i address in the thread linked below. [look for the answer labeled Proprietary Driver Issues](http://askubuntu.com/q/223501/383919)

Comment: Please be more detailed about what happens after powering on your computer.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 [is not functioning properly on a number of Intel chipsets](http://askubuntu.com/questions/806242/16-04-there-is-only-the-wallpaper-after-logging-in). Most likely your issue is not even related to the graphics card. The only solution at this stage is to return back to Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install drivers manually from a `.run` file, you need to re-install it after each kernel upgrade.

The correct way to install Nvidia drivers is from Ubuntu repositories or a PPA. The drivers are packed a way that they are rebuilt when you do a kernel upgrade.

Comment: I think that solved it. I added `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`  to my repositories and  got my drivers from there. I did that 8 weeks ago and haven't had any problems since. Here is a link to an [article](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/24/nvidia-367-44-support-titan-x-pascal-gtx-1060/)  I stumbled across, it describes the process.

Answer (score 0):

Either install the nvidia through the additional drivers settings or install dkms before you install the drivers next time so that you won't have to reinstall them afterwards.

Comment: This will not work for UEFI based systems and has a limited scope for applicable use cases.

Comment: All Nvidia drivers can be installed from repos, and it does not matter is it UEFI or not.

Comment: They can b installed, but it does not mean it will work and it actually does matter bwcause the drivers are not signed. if u use UEFI with ubsigned drivers, u see this issue pop up. Do your homework and know waht youre talking about.

Comment: @jargonjunkie It looks like someone else needs to do their homework :) maybe  you are referring to the opnsource nouveau drivers, that's not what we are talking about. Also, do you even know what DKMS is? It might benefit you to read the proprietary install.sh file before you run it next time, I'm pretty sure it's towards the very end of the file where the dkms code commands are written into the script, I don't remember though because it has been a few months since I last took a look.

Comment: Ill check it out.

Comment: @jargonjunkie It looks like that referenced solution you posted simply switched you back to nouveau so there very well could be quite a number of other reasons for your problem such as having the wrong driver version installed for your card or a missing or improperly implemented configuration file somewhere.

Comment: i am running the proprietary drivers and it works, kind of. Temporary solution since i have a lot going on. If read the link in my post, ull get the gist of it. nouveau doesnt play nice in my system as it is.