# DisplayPort Chaining crashes display manager

Tags: multiple-monitors, lightdm, cinnamon, displayport

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell laptop with a dell dock. (Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller)

I have two monitors running via display port and want to add a third.

I dual boot windows so know that the monitor chaining works correctly with the monitors and the dock, however when I boot into Ubuntu (cinnamon with lightdm) as soon as the login screen loads the entire system locks up.

I have some experience manually configuring monitors.xml and have it setup correctly for my first two monitors.

If anyone can point me in the right direction (i.e. what log files to look at, suggestions for what's causing the crash) I would greatly appreciate it!

Noe: I have looked through the Xorg log files and con't see anything out of the ordinary.

My understanding is that the dock itself acts as a displayport splitter, so the monitor that I'm trying to connect is the second/third in the link.

i.e. Laptop -> Dock -> Monitor1 -> Monitor2

If anyone needs more information, please let me know what you need and I'll try to post it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please help us help you by [edit]ing the output of `xrandr -q` into your post. A [pastie](https://pastebin.com/) of `/var/log/Xorg.log` might also be helpful.

Comment: @ElderGeek I would love to add the output of xrandr -q, however whenever I run xrandr my system freezes. As it's my work computer, I wont be able to add any details from Xorg.log till tomorrow, but will as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my issue was not to do with DP1.2 chaining, but with the graphics support for my laptop.

After considerable amounts of searching online, I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766931/how-to-change-graphics-driver-in-16-04-from-i915-to-open-source-driver/772032#772032) post which indicated that updating my kernel version should improve support for my Dell laptop.

I have now upgraded to 4.6 and all my displays are working properly.

Hope this helps people in future.

Comment: Does `xrandr -q` still crash your system?

Comment: No - everything seems to be working properly since the kernel update.